# Lazy loading a named router outlet

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, router, router-outlet

So far I have not found a working demo with lazy loading in a named router outlet e.x. `<router-outlet name="view"></router-outlet>`. I have made a plunkr to find a way to make it work without success. Any help would be much appreciated.

https://plnkr.co/edit/EW3PZUMC63euf2QYxtW5?p=preview

In the example above View1, View2 and View3 are lazy loaded in the default router-outlet. View3_1 and View3_2 are lazy loaded in the named router-outlet without success.

Comment: Updated your plunkr to https://plnkr.co/edit/bhPyG3?p=preview since it had some error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 Lazy loading with named router-outlet not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482230/angular-4-lazy-loading-with-named-router-outlet-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I had tried to do it, but got :

> Promise rejection: Invalid configuration of route 'yourRouteName': a componentless route cannot have a named outlet set

When we use named router-outlet it need component, not a module.
I think it's impossible =( But i so need it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a proxy component workaround:
We have this

```
 {
        path: 'me',
        outlet: 'hub',
        component: ProxyRouteComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: 'hub#HubModule',
            },
        ],
    },
```

Where proxy route component is simply

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'b-proxy-route',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
})
export class ProxyRouteComponent {
}
```

Comment: That seems viable.  Any insights/caveats after doing this?  Would love to see a plunker.